# Random walking. Number of steps before absorption.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

We have a symetric random walking. Random variables $\xi_i: P(\xi_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2}, P(\xi_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}, \forall i$. Random walking $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \xi_k, S_0 = 0$. Denote $\alpha_p = min(n : |S_n| = p)$. I need to calculate $E\alpha_p$. I did the following: if $p = 1$ obviously that $E\alpha_1 = 1$. Assume that $p = 2$, it's not difficult to verify that $P(\alpha_2 = 2) = \frac{1}{2}, P(\alpha_2 = 4) = \frac{1}{2}, P(\alpha_2 = 6) = \frac{1}{2}$ and so on. We have that $E\alpha_2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k}{2} = \infty$. Also, it's obviously that $\forall p_1, p_2 : p_2 > p_1 \rightarrow E\alpha_{p_1} < E\alpha_{p_2}$. Thereby $E\alpha_p = \begin{cases}\
1, & \text{p = 1} \\ 
\infty, &p > 1
\end{cases}$

Could you please tell me if I have solved everything that is written correctly?
 (this result seems a bit paradoxical).

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. The expectation $\mathbb{E} \alpha_p$ is finite for any $p \geq 1$.

Comment: But where is a mistake? In calculation of probabilities $P(\alpha_2 = 2), P(\alpha_2 = 4) ...$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $P(\alpha_2=4)$ calculation is not right. It is actually $1/4$. Likewise,  $P(\alpha_2=6)=1/8$ and so on. Computing the expectation, we get $$E(\alpha_2)=4$$

Before computing expectation, you can already know that your probabilities are not correct because they don’t add up to 1 over all k.

Actually, finding the $E(\alpha_p)$ by finding probabilities over all paths is quite tedious (okay for p values until 4, then a pain). If someone can point out a simple way to do that, I am all ears.

An easier way is to use recurrence relationships. To solve in the case of when the barriers are at $-p$ and $p$, let us denote by $E_n$, the expected lifespan if you begin at location $n$. We will finally want to find $E_0$.

Note three things 
$$E_{-p}=0$$
$$E_{p}=0$$
And the recurrence 
$$E_n=1+\frac{E_{n-1}}{2}+ \frac{E_{n+1}}{2}$$ The intuition behind this is that if we start from position $n$, we end up at $n-1$ or $n+1$ after 1 step with probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ each and each of the $E$ terms on the RHS of the equation give the expected lifespan from the new location.

For the recurrence, we try a solution $E_n=a+bn +cn^2$. Plugging that into the recurrence equation and the two boundary conditions, we get 
$$a=p^2, b=0, c=-1$$

Or $E_n=p^2-n^2$ or $E_0=p^2$.  So we have $$E(\alpha_p)=E_0=p^2$$

Comment: You are right about the statement, that $E(\alpha_p)$ is an increasing function of p, a statement that can be deduced without actually solving for the expectation.

Comment: @DF Thanks for the question. I’ve been tinkering with binomial trees etc since you asked the question, trying to use the exact distribution of the absorption time to find the expectation. If any of us can find an elegant way to do it that way, that would be worth posting too.